# Eliminar icono de botón

Tags: c#

Tengo un botón al que le agregué una imagen como icono. Ocupo que al dar click en otro botón se quite la imagen de ese botón. He intentado usar:

```cs
button.Image.Dispose();
```

Pero obtengo el error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'El parámetro no es válido.'
```

¿Qué otras formar existen para quitar una imagen de un botón o cómo se utiliza Dispose()?

Comment: Comparte todo el código que puedas, por favor, sólo con eso es difícil ver dónde está el error.

Comment: `TuBoton.Image = null;` es lo único que debe hacer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispose en condiciones normales no deberias usarlo, solo se utiliza cuando uses recursos no administrados para poderlos liberar de manera oportuna.

En tu caso bastaría con:

```
button.Image = null
```

Saludos!